# How to test correlation in this model

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, intraclass-correlation

I have a model with $n$ participants. From 5 different angles $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots, \theta_5$, each participant either responds to a stimulant with either a $0$ or a $1$, so $y_{i,\theta_j} \in \{0,1\}$ for $i=1 \dots n$, $j = 1, \dots, 5$.

For each angle $\theta_j$, I have created a response variable $z_j = \sum_{i=1}^n y_{i,\theta_j}$. I believe that as $\theta_j$ increases, $z_j$ also increases: i.e. that $\theta_j$ and $z_j$ are positively correlated.

How can I formulate this to be able to perform/get a test statistic to address the correlation between the two variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is big, by the Central Limit Theorem the conditional distribution [$Z$ given $\Theta$] is approximately Gaussian for each level $j = 1, ..., 5$. However, we cannot say much about the distribution of $\Theta$ over $j = 1, ..., 5$. For that reason the relationship between $Z$ and $\Theta$ may not be linear even if it is monotonic. To test whether a (non-)linear relationship exists you can use rank-based measures of association, like [Kendall's tau](http://www.stanfordphd.com/KendallsTau.html) or [Spearman's rho](http://www.stanfordphd.com/SpearmansRho.html). Randomization tests can be used to check their significance.

You do have to play down your expectations since the sample size of 5 offers very little statistical power. Most tests are likely to come out as statistically non-significant even if the true underlying relationship is non-zero... If there were reasonable justifications for a Gaussian nature of $\Theta$, then we could prove that any potential relationship between $Z$ and $\Theta$ must be linear. With that we could use the good-old t-test for correlation between $Z$ and $\Theta$. It would be somewhat more powerful than randomization tests for Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho.